# Same layout for large and xlarge devices

Tags: android, android-layout

My app has one layout for smartphone and one for tablets.

I want to use the same layout for both `large` and `xlarge` devices.

I want to support devices that use API 10 and up, so using `sw<N>dp` is out of the question.

How can I do that without putting the same xml file in both folders. I don't want to make code duplication. That's against any decent programming principles. :)

Comment: Could you just put that layout in the defualt bucket and make layouts for `small` and `normal` sizes?

Comment: I think that's the same problem. I have to make the same layout for small and normal sizes...

Comment: Ohh.. so same layout for large and xlarge, and same layout for small and normal? I get it... hmm... that is an interesting problem indeed then...

Comment: i think using "weight" attribute and using nine patch images will solve your problem. but its all depends on complexity of your layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that a xlarge device would use a "large" resource if there's no xlarge option in the application.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

So you can use only one XML to support either large or xlarge devices.

Comment: You are right!
This is not my first project like this. Last time I tried your approach and it didn't work. On xlarge devices it was using the xml from layout folder, not layout-large. It was strange...
That's why I didn't even considered your approach. Anyway, thanks for making be try again :)